# What is the cleanest way in swift to throw an optional error?

Tags: swift, try-catch, option-type, throws

To unwrap an optional and pass it to a function I normally use:

```
var optionalInt: Int?

optionalInt.map { someFunctionThatTakes(aNonOptional: $0) }
```

Now I have an optional error that I would like to throw if it is not nil:

```
var optionalError: Error?

optionalError.map { throw $0 }
```

This won't work because the closure passed to map can't throw.

An alternative solution would be to youse the full `if let` syntax:

```
if let theError = optionalError { throw theError }
```

But this uses the variable name `theError` twice and is more error prone than the beautiful `.map` implementation.

Does anyone know a cleaner way to implement this?

Comment: Use try in front of your map statement

Comment: I would suggest you use if let and guard let for optional handling.

Comment: beautiful .map? I think optional unwrapping is much better.

Comment: How do you end up with an optional error? Seems a bit curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This won't work because the closure passed to map can't throw.

That's not true. The closure passed to

```
func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

*can* throw an error. But that makes the `map()` call itself a (re-)throwing expression, therefore it must be called with `try`:

```
var optionalError: Error?
// ...
try optionalError.map { throw $0 }
```

I would probably still use

```
if let theError = optionalError { throw theError }
```

which is very clear, and does not use `Optional.map` for its side effects (discarding the return value of type `Void?`).

Answer (score 0):

**if you don't use `try` in front of map method it will give error**

> Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'

**Instead, use `try` to actually throw an error.**

```
enum IntParsingError: Error {
    case overflow
    case invalidInput(String)
}

var optionalError: Error? = IntParsingError.overflow

   do {
    try optionalError.map { throw $0 }
   } catch {
     print(error)
   }
```

**You can also use flatMap because of it evaluates the closure optional instance is not nil**

```
optionalError.flatMap(throw $0)
```

> But Still, If let would be the best way to handle optional error
>   instead of map and flatMap.

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension for Swift.Error

```
extension Swift.Error {
   func throwIfNeeded() throws {
       throw self
   }
}
```

And call it on optional error

```
try error?.throwIfNeeded()
```